# How do "gravity hills" work?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, perception

There are many "gravity hills" throughout the world 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_hill

I just visited one here yesterday in Burkittsville, Maryland: http://www.roadsideamerica.com/tip/600 There I put my car in neutral, and my car rolled uphill. I also spilled water on the ground, and the water traveled uphill.

One explanation is that gravity hills are an illusion caused by the landscape and the horizon. But there is a video on Youtube of a car traveling on the gravity hill in Burkittsville, Maryland in the dark, where one cannot see the landscape or the horizon, only the road ahead of the car illuminated by the car's headlights. In the youtube video, the car really looks like it is traveling upward.

So how does it work?

The only non-magical explanation that I can think of is that it is an optical illusion. I am looking for a detailed answer as to how such an optical illusion works.

Comment: Do you have some specific reason why it looks uphill to you? I was trying to check several videos like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDt2zntHFOI but I just can't understand why you think it's uphill. It's less downhill than the beginning of the slope but it still looks downhill to me. Do you have some rational, not just emotional-feeling-based, way to explain why it's uphill in your opinion?

Comment: According to your Wiki link, the illusion requires *not* being able to see the horizon, so when you do it in the dark, you are providing the premise for the illusion.

Comment: @LubošMotl, it's not emotional. It's what I saw when I was there. It certainly looked like I was going uphill when I had my car in neutral.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Please link to the mentioned Youtube videos.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9469/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Wikipedia says - Optical illusion. Based on the Youtube video, I'll definitely say optical illusion.

Comment: But how does the optical illusion work in the dark?

Comment: So gravity only works in the light?

Comment: This may be better off at [Skeptics.SE](http://www.skeptics.stackexchange.com). 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in your Wikipedia link:

> The slope of gravity hills is an optical illusion, although sites are
> often accompanied by claims that magnetic or even supernatural forces
> are at work.
>
> **The most important factor contributing to the illusion is
> a completely or mostly obstructed horizon**; without a horizon, judging
> the slope of a surface is difficult as a reliable reference is
> missing. Objects one would normally assume to be more or less
> perpendicular to the ground (such as trees) may actually be leaning,
> offsetting the visual reference. The illusion is similar to the
> well-known Ames room, in which balls can also appear to roll against
> gravity.

In other words, anything that prevents you from seeing the horizon (like darkness, or surrounding hills) will allow your eyes to be tricked by the shape of the roadway.